# css box/grid layout not sitting correctly

Tags: css, layout, grid

so I'm trying to setup a box type layout on my website, but the boxes aren't fitting in place correctly (it has gaps where I want the boxes to slot in). Essentially I want my boxes to all fit together nicely with 10px margin between each box. I've setup a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SoulieBaby/qrk7L/) of what it's currently doing. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
<div class="wrapper boxes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box col-4-4">xxx</div>
    <div class="box col-1-1">xxx</div>
    <div class="box col-1-2">xxx</div>
    <div class="box col-1-1">xxx</div>
    <div class="box col-2-1">xxx</div>
    <div class="box col-4-4">xxx</div>
    <div class="box col-1-1">xxx</div>
    <div class="box col-1-1">xxx</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.container{width:1170px}
.boxes{margin:40px 0 30px}
.boxes:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}
.boxes [class*='col-']{float:left;background:#f9f}
.boxes .col-1-1{width:260px;height:160px}
.boxes .col-1-2{width:260px;height:330px}
.boxes .col-2-1{width:530px;height:160px}
.boxes .col-4-4{width:530px;height:330px}
.boxes [class*='col-']{margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px}
```

Comment: Might not be the most helpful answer, but I would suggest you use Masonry.js and do this the easy way. http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: thanks I'll look into it.. hopefully someone can help with the CSS otherwise javascript it is!